# How to use my site's 404 page?

Tags: 404

I am using Craft **only for the blog section** of my site. The rest is HTML.

How do I make my site's 404 page come up for errors in the Craft-blog section?

Do I use the errorTemplatePrefix?

Where does that go?

What to I put in there if Craft is above root and my page is mydomain.com/404.html

Answer (score 1):

Can't think of a native way to do this — a few options come to mind, none of which are ideal.

1. recreate your sites 404 page in your 404 template (should be able to just copy/paste for the most part).
2. redirect to your site's 404 page from your 404 template (i.e. redirect 'craft/templates/404.html' to 'mydomain.com/404.html'). So in your 404 template you would have:

   ```
   {%  redirect '/404.html'  %}
   ```
3. Reaching here, but you could also possibly include your 404 page in an iframe in your 404 template.

Answer (score 1):

If your current 404 page is a static HTML page, I think the simplest solution would be to just copy your existing 404 HTML page into the craft/templates folder. Craft will display an HTML page just as easily as Twig code. Just make sure the file is named `404.html` in your craft/templates folder.

If you make a change to the 404 page later, you would have to change it in two places, but that's really the only downside I can think of.

Comment: I am just wondering how that will affect URL errors on Google.

Comment: SEO-wise it works the same to your current 404. Google would request a bad link like `http://buildwithcraft.com/misspelled-docz/` and receive the 404 error and 404 page content back from the server. But the URL doesn't change to `/404.html`. It's stays the same as the requested URL. That's how an Apache server would deal with the error too.